# What does whitelisted mean for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Tags: android, android-permissions

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission say:

> If this permission is not whitelisted for an app that targets an API
>   level before Build.VERSION_CODES.Q this permission cannot be granted
>   to apps.

What does that mean and how can a permission be "whitelisted"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context to which you are speaking, some apps that target certain permissions get "grandfathered".
Per the [permission docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview):

> Over time, new restrictions may be added to the platform such that, in order to use certain APIs, your app must request a permission that it previously did not need. Because existing apps assume access to those APIs is freely available, Android may apply the new permission request to the app's manifest to avoid breaking the app on the new platform version (thereby, "grandfathering" your app for the permission). Android makes the decision as to whether an app might need the permission based on the value provided for the targetSdkVersion attribute. If the value is lower than the version in which the permission was added, then Android adds the permission.
>
> For example, the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is enforced beginning with API level 19 to restrict access to the shared storage space. If your targetSdkVersion is 18 or lower, this permission is added to your app on newer versions of Android.

Comment: I rephrased my question, I am not looking for a dictionary definition of "whitelisted" but the meaning in the context of a permission. Who whitelists a permission? The user, the OEM?

Comment: I have never heard that terminology before - to refer to the permissions declaration in the manifest as "whitelist" - but it's a sensible interpretation.

Comment: @Manuel I've updated the answer for something more accurate.

Comment: Thanks, that corroborates that "whitelist" is referring to adding the permission to the manifest. I am just curious were that terminology suddenly comes from.